# How to create an ordered column based on values in another column (NOT a cumulative count though)?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = [
    ["Item_1", "2020-06-01"],
    ["Item_1", "2021-05-01"],
    ["Item_1", "2019-02-10"],
    ["Item_2", "2020-04-01"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-05-01"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-05-01"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-05-06"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Dates"])
df
```

I have a dataframe containing a column with a list of identifiers, and a list of dates. I would like to find a way to get the sequential counts of dates as a new column. I have done a `groupby` to a `cumcount()` however it doesn't take into account cases where the date is the same and thus the sequential count should also be the same.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
Item ID     Dates    Date Order
Item 1   2019-02-10      1
Item 1   2020-06-01      2
Item 1   2020-06-03      3
Item 2   2018-05-01      1
Item 2   2018-05-01      1
Item 2   2018-06-01      2
Item 2   2018-06-03      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can [`group`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the dataframe on `Item Id`, then [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html) the `Dates` column using `method='dense'`

```
df = df.sort_values(['Item_ID', 'Dates'], ignore_index=True) # Use if sorting required
df['Date Order'] = df.groupby('Item_ID')['Dates'].rank(method='dense')
```

---

```
  Item_ID       Dates  Date Order
0  Item_1  2019-02-10           1
1  Item_1  2020-06-01           2
2  Item_1  2021-05-01           3
3  Item_2  2018-05-01           1
4  Item_2  2018-05-01           1
5  Item_2  2018-05-06           2
6  Item_2  2020-04-01           3
```

Comment: Cleaner solution.